# Disable calendar dates between to dates in Sharepoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint, calendar

I am making a booking application in Sharepoint and want to disable dates on the calendar that is already booked. I have started and got stuck here.

```
DateTime dateStart = DateTime.Parse(radSP["StartDatum"].ToString());
DateTime dateEnd = DateTime.Parse(radSP["StartDatum"].ToString()); 

               while (dateStart < dateEnd)
               {
                   Calendar2.SelectedDate = dateStart;
                   Calendar2.SelectedDate.Day.IsSelectable = false;
                   dateStart.AddDays(1);
                   e.Day.IsSelectable = false;   //dont have acces on "e"                    
                   e.Cell.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray; //dont have acces on "e"                      
               }
```

My dates are stored in a list in Sharepoint